# Android Calendar Sample like Google Calendar

Tags: android, calendar, google-calendar-api

I would like to add a calendar in my android app where user can see their daily schedule, just like google calendar app. Any sample project or guideline is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to manage your schedule in a calendar, you can integrate `Google Calendar`, check [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/?csw=1). This is a tutorial showing you how to integrate it.

If you just want to select a date through a `popped-up calendar view`, you could look for third-party calendar libraries, like [android-times-square](https://github.com/square/android-times-square), [Android-MonthCalendarWidget](https://github.com/romannurik/Android-MonthCalendarWidget)...and google to find more.

Answer (score 3):

I made this Calendar Library for Android as part of my side project. Hope it helps someone, below is the link to the github and it has all the instructions on how to use it. If you still come across any difficulty implementing it let me know. Happy to help.

https://github.com/ik024/CalendarLibrary

[image] [image]

Thanks.

Comment: what are the advantages of use this library?

Comment: @Kuriel U can customize the look and feel of the calendar to match with your app theme.

Comment: Does it show events? Or is it just a datepicker?

Comment: @ChrisNeve If you are asking if it automatically fetches events from google and show it then no it does not but you can pass in the dates and it will mark those dates as shown above.

Comment: Is there any way it can show several events per day, in the month view, with different lines/dots of different colours in each day?

Comment: @ChrisNeve No it does not have that feature yet

Comment: How to customize above Calendar like adding events to specific date with count and also how to customize theme ?Please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

Here is another calendar sample app:

https://github.com/ShirlyK/android-calendar

[image]

Comment: This is just a datepicker I presume? It doesn't integrate with a calendar provider and display events?

Comment: This is a custom calendar that is build from ViewPager, GridLayout and java.util.Calendar.