# Google Calendar API in my application

Tags: android, google-api, google-calendar-api

Is it possible to display google calendar API and the events in my application?
I searched for a long time and I didn't find it.

Comment: Do you want to use API or just show calendar in your app?

Comment: I want to use API and show calendar in my app,
really I want to show the calendar and the events on the calendar

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, it's possible as mentioned in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/).

> Use the Google Calendar API to achieve deeper integration with Google Calendar. Mobile apps, Web apps, and other systems can create, display, or sync with Calendar data.

You may want to start with [Android Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android) which gives step-by-step tutorial.

Then, check examples from the following:

- [Android Calendarview Example](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/widget/android-calendarview-example/)
- [Android Calendar Sample like Google Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29820841).

Comment: Thank you, I think the  Android Quickstart what I'm looking for